# Using arrow to return accumulator in reduce

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know there are many similarly-phrased questions, but mine hasn't quite been answered yet.

Suppose the basic snippet below:

```
const names = {
    bob: 20,
    john: 25,
    michael: 30
};

const result = Object.entries(names).reduce(
  (acc, [name, age]) =>
    acc.push(`${name} is ${age}`) && acc,
  [] as string[]
);
```

This code works, but typescript doesn't like it and throws the error:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string[]'
```

No idea where it's getting `number` from, but all errors disappear when I do this:

```
const result = Object.entries(names).reduce(
  (acc, [name, age]) =>
    (acc.push(`${name} is ${age}`) as 1) && acc,
  [] as string[]
);
```

This works too:

```
. . .
(acc.push(`${name} is ${age}`) as {}) && acc,
. . .
```

Obviously, the following removes the error as well:

```
const result = Object.entries(names).reduce(
  (acc, [name, age]) => {
    acc.push(`${name} is ${age}`)

    return acc;
  },
  [] as string[]
);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why not a straight `map()` transform? The `reduce()` here seems extraneous. The use of `&&` is also pretty outrageous. Your `return` version is easily understood, there's zero ambiguity, but the other version is just plain weird.

Comment: I echo @tadman's comment, but to further elucidate - the `number` type arises because that's what `push` returns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value

Answer (score 2):

the number comes from `push` function whitch

> Appends new elements to the end of an array, and returns the new length of the array.

that means for typescript, your code here

```
acc.push(`${name} is ${age}`) && acc
```

- could be number for case 0
- or string for case greater than 0

so the error should more details be

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: [string, number], currentValue: [string, number], currentIndex: number, array: [string, number][]) => [string, number], initialValue: [string, number]): [...]', gave the following error.
> Type '0 | string[]' is not assignable to type '[string, number]'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type '[string, number]'.

Answer (score 1):

As far as TypeScript is concerned, [`arr.push` returns `number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value), which is *any number* type. This includes `0`, negative numbers, `NaN`, and `Infinity`. I know that `arr.push` only returns positive integers, but TS does not discern this.

Let's pretend to be the compiler for a moment...

If we know that the expression looks like this:

```
<some number type> && <string[] type>
```

and we consider the case where the number is `0` or `NaN`... then we can see that the type of this expression is `number`, because of [short-circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation):

```js
console.log(0 && []);   // => 0
console.log(NaN && []); // => NaN
```

So as you can see, that's why TypeScript believes that a `number` can be the result of this expression

```
acc.push(`${name} is ${age}`) && acc
```